# Display List of JounalArticle Liferay

Tags: filter, liferay-6, assets, article, journal

I have filtered the list of all articles in the Asset Publisher and I put them in JournalArticle, now I need to display them instead of the current articles..
is there a way to do that ?

(Purpose: Add filter to the asset publisher based on the content of a select input in the structure)

I am using Liferay 6.2 ce ga2.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this how to display articles :

```
<liferay-ui:journal-article showTitle="true" articleId="<%=ids%>" groupId="<%=themeDisplay.getLayout().getGroupId()%>"/>
```